# Floating point error when accessing std::unordered_map in array of structs

Tags: c++, struct, stl, unordered-map

My code generates a C array of structs wherein a member of the struct is an STL std::unordered_map:

```
typedef struct test_s {
   int count_a;
   std::unordered_map<std::string, int> my_map;
} test_map;

typedef struct cm_example {
   int width;
   test_map *counts;
   unsigned int hasha, hashb;
} cm_sketch;
```

However when I try access the map to perform find, insert etc. I always encounter a Floating Point Exception:

```
Compile:  g++ -std=c++11 -g test_struct.cpp -o h_str
Run:  ./h_str_str agggcctttgagag 100

Output: 
Kmer name: agggcctttgagag
hash_a: 172110908 , hash_b: 1954003865, bucket: 92 
Floating point exception
```

My code is as follows:

```
cm_sketch *cm_init (int width, int seed)
{
    cm_sketch *cm;
    int i=0;

    cm = (cm_sketch *) malloc(sizeof(cm_sketch));
    cm->width = width;

    cm->counts = (test_map *) malloc (sizeof(test_map) * width);
    for (i=0; i<width; i++) {
         cm->counts[i].count_a = 0;
    }

    cm->hasha = 172110908;
    cm->hashb = 1954003865;

    return cm;
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int bucket_id=0;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
            printf ("Please provide correct number of input arguments: \n");
            printf ("./exe 1:k-mer 2:w\n");
            exit (0);
    }

    char *kmer_input = argv[1];
    int width = atoi(argv[2]);

    std::string kmer_name = kmer_input;
    std::cout << "Kmer name: " << kmer_name;
    printf("\n");

    cm_sketch *cm = cm_init(width, time(NULL));

    unsigned int hashval = hash_str(kmer_input);
    bucket_id = hash31(cm->hasha, cm->hashb, hashval) % cm->width;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::const_iterator got;
    printf ("hash_a: %d , hash_b: %d, bucket: %d \n", cm->hasha, cm->hashb, bucket_id);

    got = cm->counts[bucket_id].my_map.find(kmer_name); /* FLOATING POINT ERROR */

    if (got == cm->counts[bucket_id].my_map.end())
        cm->counts[bucket_id].my_map[kmer_name] = 1;
    else
        cm->counts[bucket_id].my_map[kmer_name]++;

   // Iterate and print keys and values of unordered_map
   for( const auto& n : cm->counts[bucket_id].my_map ) {
        std::cout << "Key:[" << n.first << "] Value:[" << n.second << "]\n";
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Floating point errors are likely the cause of "division by zero". However here the error is internal. Running in gdb gave the following:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00000000004018f1 in std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing::operator()    (this=0x607768, __num=10758833940372818866, __den=0)
at /opt/gcc/4.9.3/snos/include/g++/bits/hashtable_policy.h:449
449     { return __num % __den; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004018f1 in std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing::operator() (this=0x607768, __num=10758833940372818866, __den=0)
at /opt/gcc/4.9.3/snos/include/g++/bits/hashtable_policy.h:449
#1  0x00000000004021cc in std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_M_bucket_index (this=0x607768, 
__c=10758833940372818866, __n=0) at /opt/gcc/4.9.3/snos/include/g++/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1266
#2  0x0000000000401d68 in std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::_M_bucket_index (this=0x607768, __k=..., 
__c=10758833940372818866) at /opt/gcc/4.9.3/snos/include/g++/bits/hashtable.h:614
#3  0x0000000000401ac6 in std::_Hashtable<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::hash<std::string>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::find (this=0x607768, __k=...)
at /opt/gcc/4.9.3/snos/include/g++/bits/hashtable.h:1303
#4  0x0000000000401969 in std::unordered_map<std::string, int, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::find (this=0x607768, __x=...) at /opt/gcc/4.9.3/snos/include/g++/bits/unordered_map.h:574
#5  0x00000000004015cb in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffff7618) at test_struct.cpp:100
```

I am not very familiar with C++, and I have been struggling with this piece of code for a long time. Please help isolate the error. Am I missing something? Am I not accessing the hash_map entries correctly?

Comment: What is with all of the C code-ism?  If you are coding C++ use C++.

Comment: Using `malloc` in C++ to create objects is wrong since it does not invoke constructor. Use `new` instead.

Comment: You should learn C++ from a book. It's not much fun for us having to repeat the basics all the time. Books were invented so that we don't have to!

Comment: Best (while learning C++) to avoid explicit dynamic memory allocation, preferring to return a `cm_sketch` by value, and have it contain a `std::vector<test_map>` - then there're far fewer (but still plenty of) ways you can go wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  When you use

```
cm = (cm_sketch *) malloc(sizeof(cm_sketch));
```

You allocate enough  storage for a `cm_sketch` and you have `cm` point to it.  `malloc` though does not call the constructor for the object you created.  So right now you have a object where all of the members are uninitialized.  Using those uninitialized variables is undefined behavior.

If you need a pointer and dynamic memory allocation then you should use `new` to allocate the storage and `delete` to free it when you are done.  `new` will call the constructor making sure the object you create is initialized and `delete` will call the destructor which will destroy all the members the class contains.

Comment: The specific problem I see is that the `std::unordered_map` will not be initialized properly (i.e., its constructor will not be run).  If all your structs were Plain-Old-Data, you wouldn't have that kind of problem -- but the moment you use C++ library objects, you'll risk this kind of problem.  This is why you really don't want to mix C and C++ idioms:  choose one or the other, unless you truly know what you're doing *and* you have a really good reason...

Comment: @comingstorm Even if the struct is a POD type it still should not be done. The struct should have default constructor that default initializes all of its members so you do not use an uninitialized variable.